# Computation of large powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, self-learning

How do I check if $2^{123456789}$ is divisible by 9?

I tried using modular exponentiation but it is way too tedious.

Is there an easier or faster way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you say it's tedious $2^3 = -1(mod \; 9)$, so $2^6 = 1(mod \; 9)$. Now check what is the reminder $r$ of $123456789$ modulo $6$ and the answer should be $2^r(mod \; 9)$.

Comment: Why modulo 6 and not 9?

Comment: because $2^6 = 1(mod \; 9)$, so if $123456789 = 6t + r$, then $2^{123456789}(mod \; 9) = 2^{6t+r}(mod \; 9) = 2^{6t}2^r(mod \; 9) = 1 * 2^r(mod 9)$

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks so much

Comment: Powers of $2$ are not divisible by 9 as they do not have $3^2$ as factors.

Comment: @hypergeometric: You should write this as an answer, it's really nice.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - Thanks!  Will do.

Answer (score 2):

Powers of $2$ are not divisible by $9$ as they do not have $3^2$ as factors.